# Why new versions of Mongo are very slow compared to 3.2

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I worked on my projects with mongodb 3.2, Nodejs + Mongodb driver for nodejs and on ubuntu 16.04. Few days ago, I decided test the new versions of mongo with disapointed results. I make a test in my web app, for insert 10000 simple records. With mongodb 3.2 time of inserts is about 1 to 2 seconds. With new versions of mongo, takes minimal 10 seconds, and each time that I execute the test without closing the process, time is more. Inserting 10000 records in Mongo 3.6 or 4.0.1 takes almost one minute after many tests made on same connection

Two test was made:

- XFS FileSystem
- WiredTiger
- Intel Xeon E3-1230 v3 - 3.3 GHz - 4 core(s)
- NodeJS 8
- mongodb driver nodejs v 3.1.3
- Insert 10000 simple documents: {nombre: 'xxxx', docset_id: IncrementalNumber}

Mongodb 3.2
Tests:

1. 1400 ms
2. 1215 ms
3. 1684 ms
4. 1020 ms
5. 2300 ms

Mongodb 4.0.1 (also the same for 3.6.6)
Tests:

1. 12234 ms
2. 16456 ms
3. 27567 ms
4. 24870 ms
5. 26560 ms
6. 42654 ms